# Kotlin - Corrutinas o callbacks para retornar un arreglo de objetos obtenido asíncronamente

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**¿Cómo retornar un arreglo de objetos de cierto tipo cuando los objetos contenidos en ése arreglo se obtienen asíncronamente?**

Tengo una aplicación de Android TV codificada en Kotlin la cual contiene una clase de "apoyo" para navegar por los menús y secciones (En base a la creación de BrowseActivities que a su vez contienen BrowseFragments).

La clase de apoyo toma una variable, la cual el `MainFragment` - el fragment que funge como 'menú de inicio' comunica como 'Extra' junto al 'Intent' a la `BrowseActivity`, a su vez la `BrowseActivity` al `BrowseFragment` y en base a ésta variable - Un valor `Int` que indica el ID de la Sección - la clase de apoyo `NavHelper` revisa si dicho valor existe como clave en un `HashMap<Int,String>` y en base al valor `String` que retorna la búsqueda con éxito de dicha clave en el HashMap, realiza una llamada a una función.

La función llamada debe retornar un `SparseArray` de un objeto creado por mí llamado `MovieRow` (Funcionalmente similar al ListRow del Leanback launcher), dicho `SparseArray<MovieRow>` es llenada (Tanto en sus Rows como los elementos `Movie` del `MovieRow`) mediante llamadas a funciones las cuales peticionan a una API RESTful de forma asíncrona mediante la sentencia `doAsync` de la librería Anko de Kotlin.

El objetivo es retornar el `SparseArray<MovieRow>` obtenido mediante la función determinada hacia otro `SparseArray<MovieRow>`contenido en el `BrowseFragment`y que en base a ése `SparseArray` obtenido cargue las `MovieRows` en pantalla (Los objetos `MovieRow`).

```
   fun returnFullMovieRows() : SparseArray<MovieRow>
   {
      var myMovieRowArray : SparseArray<MovieRow>? = null
            /*Creación del SparseArray de los movieRows vacío*/
      myMovieRowArray = SparseArray<MovieRow>()
           /*Inicialización del myMovieRowArray*/
      doAsync {
            myMovieRowArray = fillMovieRowArray()
              /*fillMovieArray es una función que retorna un SparseArray<MovieRow> lleno*/
                uiThread {
                }
      }   
          if (myMovieRowArray.size() == 0) 
          {
                System.out.println("Arreglo vacío ya que la función es 
                asíncrona")
             /* Hasta éste punto, la condición aquí definida en el IF siempre se dará ya que las funciones asíncronas no pueden retornar valores */
          }
          return myMovieRowArray
  }
```

Sin embargo, me pude dar cuenta que utilizar una rutina asíncrona para llenar un arreglo con la finalidad de retornar dicho arreglo, provocará que el arreglo retorne como nulo o vacío debido a que - valga la redundancia - es una función asíncrona.

Me han mencionado que Kotlin cuenta tanto con **corrutinas** como **callbacks** para realizar ésta tarea. En mi caso ¿Cuál sería lo más óptimo de ambas posibilidades? Y además ¿Dónde puedo encontrar ejemplos claros de cómo utilizar éstas dos funcionalidades de Kotlin?

Comment: A ver si entendi, la variable `myMovieRowArray` se asigna asincronamente y necesitas saber cuando el proceso asincrono para poder obtener la varible ya asignada?

Comment: Sí, la variable se asigna (O se llena de elementos, ya que es un arreglo) de forma asíncrona (Ya que su llenado involucra llamadas a una API RESTful), pero se necesita retornarla ya llenada (después del proceso asíncrono).

Comment: En AndroidTV no puedes usar Flow o Livedata vaya implementar ViewmModel...?

Answer (score 0):

Te encontre un ejemplo pero es con corrutinas te puede servir es es el [Link](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-and-timeouts)

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CommonPool
```

import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.newSingleThreadContext
import java.util.*
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime

internal val random = Random()

fun createRandArray(n: Long): Array {
    return createRandTArray(n).toTypedArray()
}

fun createRandTArray(n: Long): IntArray {
    return random.ints(n, 0, n.toInt()).toArray()
}

var size: Long = 1_000_000
var nRepeats: Int = 11
var nDrops: Int = 1

fun  benchmark(name: String,
                  buildSortable: (Long) -> T,
                  sort: (T) -> Any) {
    val arrays = List(nRepeats) { buildSortable(size) }
    val timesMS = arrays.map { measureNanoTime { sort(it) } / 1_000_000 }.drop(nDrops) // for JVM optimization warmup
    // println(timesMS)
    println("[$name] Average sort time for array of size $size: ${timesMS.average() } ms")
}

fun main(args: Array) {
    size = 1_000_000
    nRepeats = 6

```
benchmark("Array<Int>",
        buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size).toTypedArray() },
        sort = ::mergeSort)

benchmark("ListLike Array<Int>",
        buildSortable = { size -> SortingArray(createRandTArray(size).toTypedArray()) },
        sort = { array -> mergeSortLL(array) })  // oddly ::mergeSortLL is refused

benchmark("ListLike IntArray",
        buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size).asComparableList() },
        sort = { array -> mergeSortLL(array) })  // oddly ::mergeSortLL is refused

benchmark("IntArray",
        buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
        sort = ::mergeSortIA)

benchmark("IntArray multi-thread (CommonPool) with many array copies",
        buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
        sort = { mergeSortCorou(it) })

val origContext = corouContext
corouContext = newSingleThreadContext("single thread")
benchmark("IntArray multi-thread (one thread!) with many array copies",
        buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
        sort = { mergeSortCorou(it) })
corouContext = origContext

benchmark("Java int[]",
        buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
        sort = { MergeSorter.sort(it) })
}
```

539/5000
Puede jugar con el valor timeOut (actualmente 500 ms). Cada trabajo tiene un tiempo de ejecución aleatorio diferente de 0 a 1000 ms, por lo que la mitad se ejecuta antes del tiempo de espera.

Sin embargo, es posible que tenga más dificultades para implementar esto para su problema específico. Sus cálculos deberán ser cancelables. Lea detenidamente la sección sobre cancelación en el documento que he vinculado anteriormente. Básicamente, su cálculo tiene que llamar a una de las funciones de suspensión en kotlinx.coroutines (esto es lo que hice desde que llamo demora), o usar yield o isActive.